# How to: Check if a module exists, import it in a loop and set a bit

Tags: python, loops, exception, import, module

Is there a way in python to do the following in a more elegant way?

```
try:
    from mymodule_1 import class_a as x
    bit_mymodule_1 = True
except:
    bit_mymodule_1 = False

try:
    from mymodule_2 import  class_b as y
    bit_mymodule_2 = True
except:
    bit_mymodule_2 = False
....
(More modules follow)
```

I have several own modules with own imports.
The modules have there own imports, which not every user might have.
So I want to provide functionality depending on the libs the users of my software have installed.

The way mentioned above works, but seems not very handsome.

Doing it in a loop and setting the corresponding bit seems much more apealing.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the cleanest way I know how:

Create a separate python file in the same folder where you do all you imports:

```
try:
    from mymodule_1 import class_a as x
except ImportError:
    pass

try:
    from mymodule_2 import  class_b as y
except ImportError:
    pass
```

then in your main script, from the module *moduleFinder* import ModuleFinder and your script with the imports.

```
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
import my_imports
```

Create a ModuleFinder object and make it run your script that has the imports.

```
finder = ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script('my_imports.py')
```

Finally, you can create a dictionary that replaces all those bit variables you had before

```
modules = {mod_name: True for mod_name in finder.modules}
modules.update({mod_name: False for mod_name in finder.badmodules})
```

And in your code, you can just do a lookup in the dictionary

```
if modules['mymodule_1']:
    pass
```

Comment: I tried it for some time now but I get a pretty long traceback with the last step pointing out this (from the finder.run_script function):   File "C:\__Programme\Python\Python_390\lib\modulefinder.py", line 77, in _find_module
    if spec.loader.is_package(name):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_package'                The my_imports itsself works well and can import all modules.

Comment: For the answer I actually looked at the documentation for the module as I didn't know it beforehand, you can read it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/modulefinder.html). But by the looks of it, the code is breaking because it's trying to check if a NoneType is a package. I would debug the code and see what module or line in the imports file is making the module loader act up. I could also be of more help with the full traceback exception

Comment: I am also hitting the `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_package'`.  For what it's worth, looks like `modulefinder` doesn't handle namespace packages yet per https://bugs.python.org/issue40350 as of 12/27/2021 with Python 3.8.12.  There are two currently open PRs that address the issue.

Comment: Hitting the same problem with Python 3.11.2